# How to run read() function only once Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-xd

I am creating a Spring Batch job with folowing xml:

```xml
<batch:job id="simulatorJob" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="stockListner" writer="customWriter"
                commit-interval="5">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="stockListner" class="com.XXX.stock.java.StockReader" scope="step">
    <property name="URL" value="NTPC,TCS" />
    <!-- <property name="URL" value="NTPC" /> -->
    <!-- <property name="URL" value="TCS" /> -->
</bean>

<bean id="customWriter" class="com.XXX.stock.java.FlatFileWriter" />
```

This is my reader class:

```
private String URL;

public String getURL() {
    return URL;
}

public void setURL(String uRL) {
    URL = uRL;
}

public ArrayList<StockData> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    ArrayList<StockData> list = new ArrayList<StockData>();
    String[] splitStocks = URL.split(",");      

    for(int i=0; i < splitStocks.length;i++){
        list.add(stockReader.getStockData(splitStocks[i]));     
    }
    return list;        
}
```

But the reader class keeps on running. How do I stop at first run?

I tried this aswell:

```
public StockData read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    ArrayList<StockData> list = new ArrayList<StockData>();
    String[] splitStocks = URL.split(",");

    for(int i=0; i < splitStocks.length;i++)
    {  
           return stockReader.getStockData(splitStocks[i]);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The read() function goes into loop..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple delegate encapsulate one-time reading.

```
class OneItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {
  boolean read = false;
  ItemReader<T> delegate;

  @Override
  public T read() {
    if(read) {
      return null;
    }
    T item = delegate.read();
    read = true;
    return item;
  }
}
```

You can create you own reader without think about one-time reading and wrap it using this small delegate.

Your StockURLReader may be defined as

```
class StockURLReader implements ItemReader<StockReader> {
  String[] tokens = new String[0];
  int index = 0;
  StockDAO stockReader;

  void setURL(String URL) {
    this.tokens = URL.split(",");
    index = 0;
  }

  StockData read() {
    if(index < tokens.length) {
      return stockReader.getStockData(tokens[index++]);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Create `OneTimeReader` and set `StockURLReader` as delegate and you have separate StockData reading from one-time reading logic.
If you want to read a group of `StockData` the best solution is to create a `StockDataListBean` where you store all `StockData` read from a splitted URL.

```
class StockDataListBean {
  List<StockData> data = new LinkedList<StockData>();
}
```

and modify `StockURLReader` as:

```
class StockURLReader implements ItemReader<StockDataListBean> {
  String[] URLs = new String[0];
  int index;
  StockDAO stockReader;

  void setURLs(String[] URL) {
    this.URLs = URL;
    index = 0;
  }

  StockDataListBean read() {
    StockDataListBean item = null;
    if(index < URLs.length)
    {
      item = new StockDataListBean();
      for(String token : URLs[index].split(",").length)
      {
        item.data.add(stockReader.getStockData(token));
      }
    }
    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe @Aman has more than one `StockData` item to read unlike what its first try suggested (i.e. declare `ArrayList<StockData> read()`).

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [`ItemReader.read()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html#read--) Javadoc:

> Reads a piece of input data and advance to the next one. Implementations **must** return `null` at the end of the input data set.

As such, you need to return `null` after the first read to indicate to Spring Batch that there is nothing more to read.

Comment: Your method `read()` must return only one `StockData`, not a list. Keep track of what parts of `splitStocks ` you already sent and return only one `splitStocks[i]` until there is no more and return `null` (or use a list like you started to do).

Comment: @Gael If not arraylist then how do i send multiple values of    <property name="URL" value="NTPC,TCS" />

Comment: @Gael I have tried these as per ur comments..but no luck

Comment: See my answer using `ListIteamReader`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`ListIteamReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ListItemReader.html) like this (example, not tested) :

```
public class StockReader extends ListItemReader<StockData> {

    public StockReader(String URL) {
         super(createListFromUrl(URL));
    }

    public List<StockData> createListFromUrl(String URL) {
        // create your ArrayList<StockData> list from URL
    }

}
```